# how to integrate openCV python code in Swift

Tags: python, ios, swift, opencv

I wrote a code using openCV in Python and I want to integrate it into my IOS application. Existing tutorials are outdated and I got error saying "'opencv2/core.hpp' file not found". I really appreciate if you can help me answering these:

1. Can I integrate openCV in Python directly into IOS or do
   I have to convert it to C++?
2. If I can integrate it how to do it without getting
   core.hpp error?

Comment: Aside from if it's possible or not. Running and rewriting your python code 'native' in  C++ will probably be lot more streamlined and quicker. And will most likely avoid you problems later down the road.

Comment: Did the tutorial cover the installation of openCV on MacOS? I only had experience with Windows, but I remembered I had to install openCV first before I can pip install python packages that interface with openCV.

Answer (score 0):

after a couple of days more intensive study I understood that to use OpenCV framework does not mean to integrate a python code into the Swift code. It requires to code in the .mm file with C++ syntax. There is a python to C converter called cython and you can create c extension for your code but it does not solve the problem.

The best openCV framework integration into the code described in the link below. Plus there is a sample code you can download to check. Hope it helps:

[OpenCVFramework integration in Xcode](https://www.timpoulsen.com/2019/using-opencv-in-an-ios-app.html)